# Непонятное всплывающее окно с подтверждением логина пользователя при смене парля Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Сделал кастомную смену пароля но теперь при обновлении страницы после смены пароля всплывает окно с выбором логина пользователя которое ничего не решает :([image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Django тут ни при чём, это самодеятельность вашего браузера

Comment: @andreymal, А вы не подскажите как это исправить чтобы в браузерах такого не было ?

Comment: ААаааа это что-ли смена пароля в сохраненных паролях ??